# Microsoft SQL Server Double Byte Characters

Tags: sql-server, string, double-byte

In Microsoft SQL Server, trying to put double byte characters into a string in the query will mess up the double byte strings unless there is an N front of the string, like this:

```
SELECT 'double-byte string'    -- puts question marks if string is double-byte
SELECT N'double-byte string'   -- works with double-byte strings
```

The question is: is there any way to make N the implicit default so I don't have to put N in front of every string?

Comment: No. String literals in TSQL without the `N` prefix are always treated as `varchar` in the code page of the default collation.

Comment: I'd also add that this shouldn't be a problem unless you are talking about SQL Server Manager, because in code you should be using parameterized SQL.

Comment: No, you can't make it the default. See my answer here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/20546/2718